# Styling Vaadin text-area based on class name

Tags: css, vaadin, shadow-root

We have added global styles to Vaadin text areas in our app like this:

```
[part="input-field"] {
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 191, 0.4) !important;
    border-radius: unset;
}

[part="value"] {
    color: black !important;
}

[part="value"]::after {
    color: black !important;
}
```

It works like a charm. It applies to all text-areas no matter what the classname we set since we use

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/text-area.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-area")
```

Now our users are very demanding when it comes to colors... They want this one field to have different background. Ive tried this (with classname and field id) but it doesnt have any effect and just applies the global styles anyways:

```
.hashtag-text-area [part="input-field"] {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: unset
}
```

I have also tried doing it in java with

```
area.getStyle().set(...)
```

but it changes the whole component and not just the part=value. The style just overlay and does not look like the bussiness wants it.

Im nowhere near being a front end developer thats why we use Vaadin.

Does anyone know how to get into the "part=value" of this specific field.
Do we have to give up on global styles and just rely on classnames and duplicate it X number of times for Z number of text areas so we can add classname-specific style?

Am i doing something wrong here?

This is how the html looks:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays browsers have part selector, so you can do most of the things in your global styles. So you do not need import specific style module for `vaadin-text-area`, instead just do something like this:

```
.hashtag-text-area::part(input-field) {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: unset
}
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try these?

```
:host(.hashtag-text-area) [part="input-field"] ::slotted(textarea) {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: unset;
}
```

in your `./styles/text-area.css`
or in your common styles.css without the `:host`

```
.hashtag-text-area [part="input-field"] ::slotted(textarea) {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: unset;
}
```

Comment: The second code snippet cannot work because you're mixing shadow dom css and  global css.

Comment: The first snippet has an unncessary ::slotted(textarea), when simply prefixing the selector with :host(.hashtag-text-area) is sufficient.